# Null Pointer Exception when setting button visibility

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am getting to change the visibility of one of the buttons on my viewpager but I am getting a Null Pointer Exception on this line:

```
save_button.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);
```

I am wondering why that is? Is it because I am not getting the visibility property inside of my InstantiateItem() for the button? Should I? If so, how do I change the button visibility based on the fact if the page is viewed by the user or not?

What I am trying to do is: Show the save button if all the views are viewed in the viewpager. If not all the views are viewed, then hide the save button.

Here is my code:

```
boolean isViewed = false;
boolean buttonState= false; //unpressed, if true == pressed
int buttonValue = 0;

//Methods
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.score_viewpager);

    //Specify the number of pages/views
    numberOfPages = new Integer[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    final Button save_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);

    //Initialize adapter to populate view
    myAdapter = new MyAdapter(ScoreCollectionPager.this, numberOfPages, save_button);

    //Search view for viewpager Id and set the adapter on the first item
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);

    //Attach the page change listener inside the activity
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        Button save_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);

        // This method will be invoked when the current page is scrolled
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        //This method will be invoked when a new page becomes selected
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            //get position
            isViewed = true;

            if (isViewed  && (position == numberOfPages.length)) {

                save_button.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
            }
            else {
                save_button.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE); // Null Pointer Exception here? why?
            }

        }

        // Called when the scroll state changes:
        // SCROLL_STATE_IDLE, SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING, SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {
            //get state
        }
    });

}

private class MyAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    //fields
    Button save_button;

    //Constructor
    public MyAdapter(Context context, numberOfPages, Button save_button) {

        this.context = context;
        this.numberOfPages = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(numberOfPages));
        this.save_button = save_button;

    }

    //Returns total number of pages
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return numberOfPages.size();
    }

    /**
     * Create the page for the given position.
     *
     * @param parent The containing View in which the page will be shown.
     * @param position  The page position to be instantiated.
     *
     * @return Returns an Object representing the new page. This does not need
     *         to be a View, but can be some other container of the page.
     */
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup parent, final int position) {

        //Get the inflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        //inflate the root layout
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.score_collection, null);

        //Save Button
        save_button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.save);

        save_button.setOnClickListener(new ViewGroup.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {

                //code for saving

        }});
    }
}
```

Comment: `save_button` is `null`.

Answer (score 2):

Move the below piece of code inside onPageSelected mehtod

```
 Button save_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
```

Comment: I have a question. Do I need to pass the save button to myAdapter though?

Comment: If you keep it as a final class variable you can use it directly.

Comment: While this semi-works, I am experiencing strange behavior. When my first page loads, there is a save button. When I swipe through all the views, the save button is gone. Is my logic above correct in the sense that, I want to only show the save button if ALL views are viewed.

Comment: try this logic...set the button as Invisible by default....and only when you reach the last page....set it visible. Also you dont need isViewed boolean flag as you are setting it to true before the check, makes no sense to have a condition on it. Also use the following check : if(position == numberOfPages.length-1){// set button visible}

Comment: So, should I remove isViewed variable entirely? I want to be able to know if all the views are seen by the view, then set save button to visible. Thanks

Comment: In that case you a list of all pages that have been viewed, then you can compare it with the list of all pages

Answer (score 1):

I can see that Button instances are not the same. Make sure that you get the same object in the same layout. The first 2 buttons in your code belong to layout R.layout.score_viewpager, the last one belongs to R.layout.score_collection (in MyAdapter).

Comment: You are right, it looks like i have two instances. I was wondering how would I be able to refer to the same save_button in both my activity and my adapter?

Comment: It depends on the location of your button. If it belongs to score_collection.xml, you should handle it in MyAdapter. The method instantiateItem have "position" parameter which can be used as a condition to show/hide save button.

Comment: Thank you, that works just fine (at least so far :P).

Answer (score 0):

OK. It's a mess, but if you in onCreate give value to a class variable, you can access it in the other internal classes without having to call findViewById several times (expensive call).

Class var:

```
private final Button saveButton;
```

Set value in onCreate:

```
saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
```

Comment: I have a question. I followed Kakarot's answer and I am now experiencing strange behavior: When my first page loads, there is a save button. When I swipe through all the views, the save button is gone. Is my logic above correct in the sense that, I want to only show the save button if ALL views are viewed

Comment: The logic is wrong. isViewed  && (position == numberOfPages.length) will never occur, position is zero indexed. You need to check length-1, and also the isViewed need to be per-page - not one shared flag for all pages.

Comment: Why is it wrong? How can I make isViewed "per page"? I thought isViewed = true onPageSelected?